# Can't change line to bars - chart - Google script

Tags: google-apps-script, charts, google-visualization

I want to create a chart with the code below :

```
var sht=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var chart = sht.newChart()
    .addRange(sht.getRange("B4:B11"))
    .addRange(sht.getRange("C4:C11"))
    .addRange(sht.getRange("D4:D11"))
    .addRange(sht.getRange("E4:E11"))
    .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.COMBO)
    .setPosition(2, 8, 0, 0)
    .setOption('title', 'Test')
    .setOption("series",{
      0:{type:'bars',color:'red'},
      1:{type:'bars',color:'blue'},
      2:{type:'line',color:'green'},
    })
    .build();

  sht.insertChart(chart);
```

With setOptions, I try to have two series of bars and one line, but I am not able : whatever I write, it always creates a chart with serie 0 type bars, series 1 and 2 type line.

Is there a reason?

EDIT : I also tried with code of a saved macro :

```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  
  chart = sheet.newChart()
  .asComboChart()
  .addRange(spreadsheet.getRange('B5:B11'))
  .addRange(spreadsheet.getRange('C4:C11'))
  .addRange(spreadsheet.getRange('D4:D11'))
  .addRange(spreadsheet.getRange('E4:E11'))
  .setOption('series.1.type', 'ColumnChart')
  .setOption('series.2.type', 'LineChart')
  .setPosition(4, 7, 0, 0)
  .build();

  sheet.insertChart(chart);
```

It does not work.

Thanks

Comment: This could be related to a reported open issue from https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/183272766 (Combo chart series type not working), where a user is trying to set series 0 from bar to line but it doesn't work using apps script. I tried replicating using the guide from this reference at https://tanaikech.github.io/2017/05/16/changing-line-to-bars-for-combo-chart-using-gas/ but it seems it doesn't work when applying it to your ranges as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have replicated this issue and it looks like that there is a bug on the `type:` property in `setOption()` in which it does not apply to the combo chart, thus the output is always the default type which is bars, line, line (and line for each subsequent row).

**Sample Code and Output:**

```
function myFunction() {
  var sht=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var chart = sht.newChart()
    .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.COLUMN)
    .addRange(sht.getRange("B4:F11"))
    .setPosition(2, 8, 0, 0)
    .setOption('title', 'Test')

    .build();

  sht.insertChart(chart);

  chart = chart.modify()
    .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.COMBO)
    .setOption("series",{
      0:{type:'area',color:'red'},
      1:{type:'line',color:'blue'},
      2:{type:'line',color:'green'},
      3:{type:'bars',color:'yellow'}
    })
    .build();

  sht.updateChart(chart);
}
```

[image]

You can report this on the [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191640%20status:open) so they can take a look at it, or follow this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/183272766